# What would be the recommended Java database model in this case?

Tags: java, database

I have written an app that processes a video (720*576 px, 30 fps, RGB format) using `OpenCV` under `Java`. I only calculate 5 int variables as a result of my processing on each frame. I would like to store those 5 int variables **with the current frame** in a dataset, and I therefore need to do that **several times per second** (30 times/sec would be ideal, but I could do with less by grouping the data, I guess...).

What would be the right database choice for such a thing? I was thinking `HDF5`, would that be a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about anything would work.

The issue of "30 times a second" should be within the capability of any database or dataset file format.  If there are problems keeping up, they can be handled:

- by either batching the inserts (for a database or access library),
- by writing to a buffered stream, or
- by using an in-memory queue and separate Java threads for frame processing and saving the extracted data.  (Assuming that you are processing frames in real-time.)

I would chose a database / library / format based on the *other* things that you want it to do.  The performance should not be a concern for what you are proposing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily, (on most modern systems), write 5 integer values 4 commas and linefeed to a file on hard disk at 30 writes per second and with a much lower overhead than a DB.  Try keeping it simple and write to a csv file - most databases can import from a csv file without problems if you need it in a database later.

Comment: yes, however I wanted to add the current processed frame too, which means I would put 720*576*3 = 1244160 float variables + 5 int variables at 30 writes/sec... Does your answer still hold in that case, or do you think I then need an alternate solution?